# Subclass methods being ignored in Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have some confusion about an error in my Obj-C project. What I'm doing is fairly simple and don't understand what I am missing here. I am just creating a very simple method in a subclass of UIImageView, and then instantiating that class. When I try to use the method from my instance, the compiler complains it is not implemented (although it is)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

In my .h file:

```
@interface CwheelElement : UIImageView { 
int type;
int position;
int row;
float rotation;
}

- (CwheelElement *) initWithType:(int) iType andPosition:(int) iPosition onRow:(int) iRow;
- (void) rotateByRadians:(float) iRadians;

- (void) test;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int type;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int position;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int row;

@end
```

In my .m file:

```
- (CwheelElement *) initWithType:(int) iType andPosition:(int) iPosition onRow:(int) iRow {
 self = [super init];

 /* …stuff */

 return self;
}

- (void) test {
 NSLog(@"testing");
}
```

Trying to use the class:

```
CwheelElement *iElement = [[CwheelElement alloc] initWithType:row3WheelTypes[i] andPosition:i onRow:3];
   [lowerWheelElements addObject:iElement];

   [iElement test];
```

I get the following errors:

**2010-09-13 02:13:08.431 spinnerX[7329:207]**  -[UIImageView test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d0e710
2010-09-13 02:13:08.432 spinnerX[7329:207]  **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIImageView test]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d0e710'**

It says that the [CwheelElement test] isn't implemented, but it is... any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I discovered buried in my initializer the following line:

```
self = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pieceGraphicFilename]];
```

I changed it to the following and am no longer having the issue:

```
self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:pieceGraphicFilename];
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution, I was doing the same thing with one of my sub-classes.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, it is strongly recommended to return (id) from initializer in order not to run yourself in the same problem while subclassing.

```
- (id) initWithType:(int) iType andPosition:(int) iPosition onRow:(int) iRow;
```